# Nuxt 3 use composable in middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, vuejs3, middleware, nuxtjs3

I want to guard a route by checking if the user is logged in, but:

1. I can't read the composable value,
2. I am unsure if my middleware got the right body.

---

My composable:

```js
// composable/useAuth.js
const useAuth = () => {

  // user login, sign out, sign up logic

  const isLoggedIn = () => {
    return !!user.value
  }

  return {
    isLoggedIn
  }
}

export default useAuth
```

My middleware:

```js
// middleware/check-admin.js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuth()

  console.log(isLoggedIn); // <- Screenshot

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return navigateTo(`/albums/${to.params.id}/edit`)
  } else {
    return navigateTo('/')
  }
})
```

My console logs a method body. But I expected a falsy or truthy value:
[image]

---

#### Problems:

- How can I read a boolean value from my composables to pass the test inside the middleware?
- It is okay to use `navigateTo` to abort the routing, if the user got no credentials? The docs says, I can use `abortNavigation()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You returning function, but never invoke it by using `()` at the end.

Try like this:

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuth()

  console.log(isLoggedIn()); // <- Screenshot
  // `from.name === login` will trigger rediraction for example if user want to login but he is already logged in.
  // form.name will be necesery if you use suffix `.global` in file name.
  if (isLoggedIn() && to.params.id && !from.params.id && from.name === `login`) {
    return navigateTo(`/albums/${to.params.id}/edit`)
  }
  if (!isLoggedIn() && form.params.id) {
    return abortNavigation()
  }
})
```

Use `to` value to know where user want to navigate.

You can choose where to use middleware in component if you're not using `.global` suffix in middleware file.

```html
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  middleware: ["auth"]
  // or middleware: 'auth'
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right with the init. But I got this warning: `[Vue Router warn]: Detected an infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/albums/4" to "/albums/4/edit"`

Comment: This is why you need to use `(to, from)` values in `if` statements.

Comment: If he is already in `/albums/${to.params.id}/edit` navigation will navigate user again because it's triggering every time user navigate somewhere.

Comment: You have functions to abort navigation, use them if user is already in a route where he should be.

Comment: @wittgenstein I don't know what you want to achieve, but code should look like mine.

Comment: It gets me closer. Now if I am unauthorized, I am getting an Error `500 Route navigation aborted: /albums/74/edit`. But that's another topic. First I wanted to get a feeling how I use a composable in a middleware. Thanks!